# Remove whitespace between two lowercase letters

Tags: python, nlp

Trying to find a regex (or different method), that removes whitespace in a string only if it occurs between two lowercase letters. I'm doing this because I'm cleaning noisy text from scans where whitespace was mistakenly added inside of words.

For example, I'd like to turn the string `noisy = "Hel lo, my na me is Mark."` into `clean= "Hello, my name is Mark."`

I've tried to capture the group in a regex (see below) but don't know how to then replace only whitespace in between two lowercase letters. Same issue with re.sub.

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work because it removes all the whitespace from the string:

```
import re

noisy = "Hel lo my name is Mark"

finder = re.compile("[a-z](\s)[a-z]")
whitesp = finder.search(noisy).group(1)
clean = noisy.replace(whitesp,"")

print(clean)
```

Any ideas are appreciated thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
My use case is for Swedish words and sentences that I have OCR'd from scanned documents.

Comment: How would you distinguish the space between "Hel lo" and "my name"?

Quick suggestion: you might want to try using pre-trained BPE tokenizers on the sentences for which you've deleted all spaces. There are such tokenizers on Huggingface.

Comment: removing whitespace in a string "only if it occurs between two lowercase letters" seems easy enough, but I don't think it will give the result you're looking for... wouldn't you then end up with `"Hellomynameis Mark"`?

Answer (score 1):

To correct an entire string, you could try [`symspellpy`](https://symspellpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

First, install it using pip:

```bash
python -m pip install -U symspellpy
```

Then, import the required packages, and load dictionaries. Dictionary files shipped with `symspellpy` can be accessed using `pkg_resources`. You can pass your string through the `lookup_compound` function, which will return a list of spelling suggestions (`SuggestItem` objects). Words that require no change will still be included in this list. `max_edit_distance` refers to the maximum edit distance for doing lookups (per single word, not entire string). You can maintain casing by setting `transfer_casing` to `True`. To get the clean string, a simple join statement with a little list comprehension does the trick.

```py
import pkg_resources
from symspellpy import SymSpell

sym_spell = SymSpell(max_dictionary_edit_distance=2, prefix_length=7)

dictionary_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(
    "symspellpy",
    "frequency_dictionary_en_82_765.txt"
)

bigram_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(
    "symspellpy",
    "frequency_bigramdictionary_en_243_342.txt"
)

sym_spell.load_dictionary(dictionary_path, term_index=0, count_index=1)
sym_spell.load_bigram_dictionary(bigram_path, term_index=0, count_index=2)

my_str = "Hel lo, my na me is Mark."

sugs = sym_spell.lookup_compound(
    my_str,
    max_edit_distance=2,
    transfer_casing=True
)

print(" ".join([sug.term for sug in sugs]))
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is Mark
```

Check out their [documentation](https://symspellpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for other examples and use cases.

Comment: Nice answer. It can be improved if you update it with a little explanation of the `pkg_resources` usage here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Just edited it to clarify its' use.

Comment: When I run the code you posted above the output is "Hel lo my na me is Mark", so the input unchanged. I pip installed -U symspellpy like you suggested and changed nothing else. Any ideas why it doesn't work? Also edit: my use case is in Swedish, but it seems like symspellpy might still work?

Comment: @steca apologies, I left out two *very* important lines of code to load in the dictionaries! Edited my above solution to reflect the changes. The dictionaries I used are both English so you would have to find Swedish dictionaries for your use case. The original C# [source code](https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell) may be able to help you locate other frequency dicts. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```py
In [3]: finder = re.compile("([a-z])\s([a-z])")

In [4]: clean = finder.sub(r'\1\2', noisy, 1)

In [5]: clean
Out[5]: 'Hello my name is Mark'
```

Comment: IMHO, the solution is not right, since it will only work for the first occurrence of the pattern. I'm under the impression that's not the outcome the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Python module that contain words (like an oxford dictionary) that can check for any valid words in the string by matching the character that has space in between, for example, you can break the string into list `string.split()` then loop the list starting with index 1 `range(1,len(your_list))` by joining the current index and the previous index `list[index - 1] + list[index]` into a string (i.e., token/word); then use this token to check the set of words that you have collected to see if this token is a valid word; if is true, append this token into a temporary list, if not true then just append the previous word into the temporary list, once the loop is done, you can just join the list into a string.

You can try Python spelling checker [pyenchant](https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/), Python grammar checker [language-check](https://pypi.org/project/language-check/), or even using [NLTK Corpora](https://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/) to build your own checker.